# why i am getting 500 internal error in ajax code

Tags: jquery, ajax

Here is my code where I am getting error what m doing wrong there :

Ajax Call back Code:

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#btn2').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
                var cate=$( "#cate option:selected").val();
                var sub_cat=$( "#myselect option:selected").val();
                var price=$('#price').val();
                var dprice=$('#dprice').val();
                var fprice=$('#fprice').val();
                var payment=$('input[name=payment]:checked').val();
                 var url="<?php echo base_url();?>cat_cntrl/submitalldata";
                $.ajax({
                type:'post',
                url:url,
                data:{cate :cate, sub_cat:sub_cat,price :price,dprice:dprice,fprice:fprice,payment:payment},
                dataType:"JSON",
                success:function(response){
    alert(response);
                }

    })
    })
        })
```

Controller funcation to get data and return data :

```
 public function submitalldata(){


          $cate=$this->input->post('cate');
          $sub_cat=$this->input->post('sub_cat');
          $price=$this->input->post('price');
          $dprice=$this->input->post('dprice');
          $fprice=$this->input->post('fprice');
          $payment=$this->input->post('payment');
          $data=array(
                 'category'=>$cate,
                 'subcat'=>$sub_cat,
                 'price'=>$price,
                 'discount'=>$dprice,
                 'finalprice'=>$fprice,
                 'paymentmode'=>$payment,
                 'createddate'=>time()
                     );

$get=$this->cat_model->insert('task',$data);
echo $this->db->last_query();
         // print_r($get);exit;
      $data['result']=$get;
     //print_r($data['result']);exit;
      echo $this->db->last_query();

     echo json_encode(array('result'=>$data['result']));
 }
```

On console m getting error 500 Internal Server Error what I am doing wrong there can anyone pls help me related this

Comment: use browser inspector to view the JSON that you post to server, it might be missing or some field might be invalid to parse on server

Comment: Getting a HTTP 500 basically means the same as "it doesn't work". Check your server logs for any clues or enable error reporting.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer: it was my mistake in the controller file. Sorry to all of you.

```
$get=$this->cat_model->insert('task',$data); instead of this i used

$get=$this->db->insert('task',$data);
```